# SAP B1 Integration framework XPATH to read webservice XML response

Tags: xml, xpath, sapb1

I have a B1IF package which call a webservice to export some data from B1

When I call this webservices I get an XML as response, but I can't read it.

This is what I get from the webservice

```
<Payload Role="C" id="atom24" statusNo="0" statusMsg="success" reference="atom25" payload="atom25" calltype="solicit response (call/reply)" adapter="WSAS">
<http.header>
<http.header.info id="Cache-Control" value="private, max-age=0"/>
<http.header.info id="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
<http.header.info id="x-frame-options" value="sameorigin"/>
<http.header.info id="Content-Length" value="367"/>
<http.header.info id="X-XSS-Protections" value="1"/>
<http.header.info id="Date" value="Thu, 03 Dec 2020 17:20:50 GMT"/>
<http.header.info id="Content-Type" value="text/xml; charset=utf-8"/>
</http.header>
<LoadXmlResponse>
<LoadXmlResult><error></error></LoadXmlResult>
</LoadXmlResponse>
</Payload>
```

XML RESPONSE:
[image: XML RESPONSE]

I'd like to test the response in a "path" atom
PATH ATOM:
[image: PATH ATOM]

I can't find the correct xpath expression to read the  from the XML response.

I tried these:

```
/*[/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@Role='C' and @id='atom24']/LoadXmlResponse/LoadXmlResult/error='']

/*[/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@Role='C' and @id='atom24']/LoadXmlResponse/LoadXmlResult='<error></error>']

/*[/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[@Role='C' and @id='atom24']/@statusMsg="success"]
```

But without success.

Comment: Please update your question and add XML response as a text. Pictures are not helpful.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky thanks Yitzhak, I added response as a text as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath attempts show **Msg** and **Body** XML elements. They are missing in the provided input XML. Same about namespaces.

In any case, here is Working XPath expressions for the input XML.

```
/Payload/@calltype

/Payload/http.header/http.header.info[@id="Date"]

/Payload/LoadXmlResponse/LoadXmlResult
```

Comment: thanks, but I need to get the <LoadXmlResult><error></error></LoadXmlResult> information, not the http.header.info

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
[./@Role=&apos;C&apos; and ./@Id=&apos;atom24&apos;]/LoadXmlResponse/LoadXmlResult/error
```

I'm not sure if you need to use a special namespace before every tag you want (like we need jdbc: before every tag in sql result)

If it doesn't work you can use another xslt atom there you can put

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/vpf:Msg/vpf:Body/vpf:Payload[./@Role=&apos;C&apos; and ./@Id=&apos;atom24&apos;]/*"></xsl:copy-of>
```

It will give you all the content in a simple xml file from there you will able to retrieve the information by using tagName/tagName... with out a special namespace.